# Chat bot Hands-Off published on azure - gives connection error emulator :Cannot post activity. Unauthorized

Tags: botframework

I have been trying to host bot which works on local to the Azure Hosting.
I'm trying to connect hosted bot with local emulator gives connection error (emulator :Cannot post activity. Unauthorized).

My .bot file:

```
{
  "name": "production",
  "description": "",
  "services": [
    {
      "type": "endpoint",
      "appId": "********************",
      "appPassword": "*************",
      "endpoint": "intermediatorbotsample2019.azurewebsites.net/api/messages",
      "name": "AzureAccountLive",
      "id": "178"
    }
  ],
  "padlock": "",
  "version": "2.0",
  "path": "D:\\Architecture\IntermediatorBot\\production.bot",
  "overrides": null
}
```

Comment: Hi Pranav! Have you updated your .bot file to include a 'production' endpoint with your AppID and AppPassword?

Comment: Thanks for your answer can you be more through to resolve this issue.  Chat bot Hands-Off published on azure - gives connection error emulator :Cannot post activity. Unauthorized.    This project seams work fine on local without Azure credentials  but same after hosting  shows me Error .  I do have included .bot file to include a 'production' endpoint with your AppID and AppPassword . Though it work on local . But after deploying it on azure i am unable to receive response .

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your .bot file (you can block out the appID and PW)

Comment: {
    "name": "production",
    "description": "",
    "services": [
        {
            "type": "endpoint",
            "appId": "********************",
            "appPassword": "*************",
            "endpoint": "http://intermediatorbotsample2019.azurewebsites.net/api/messages",
            "name": "AzureAccountLive",
            "id": "178"
        }
    ],
    "padlock": "",
    "version": "2.0",
    "path": "D:\\Architecture\IntermediatorBot\\production.bot",
    "overrides": null
}

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Re genreted  AppId and secret from https://dev.botframework.com/.

Previously was using `AzureBotProject` replaced it with `AzureBotChannelProject` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at your bot file in your comment. The problem is that you have "name": "AzureAccountLive" in your services section. This name MUST be "production". The outer level "name" has to match the name of the bot (in this case, it's probably intermediatorbotsample2019). It's the Name:Production, Type:Endpoint combination that ABS looks for. If you update your botfile to match what I have below, your bot should work as expected.

```
 {
  "name": "YOURBOTNAMEHERE",
  "description": "",
  "services": [
    {
      "type": "endpoint",
      "appId": "********************",
      "appPassword": "*************",
      "endpoint": "http://intermediatorbotsample2019.azurewebsites.net/api/messages",
      "name": "production",
      "id": "178"
    }
  ],
  "padlock": "",
  "version": "2.0",
  "path": "D:\\Architecture\IntermediatorBot\\production.bot",
  "overrides": null
}
```